# android push notification is appeared on the screen and also approve/reject buttons are enabled without unlock the screen

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my android app,I have a problem with push notification concept. When I send notification, it appears on the screen and I am able to click approve/reject buttons BUT I should not have this ability before I unlock the screen. How could I find a way out for this problem? I am asking now maybe any of you are came across with this problem before and whether you handle it. I need to know that how can I do such a thing that I mentioned above. In fact, asking for idea not coding.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi Ayso. Welcome to Stack Overflow. As it currently stands, the community won't be able to help you if you don't provide the code you have that is showing the issue. As much as possible, please provide relevant information on your posts. Cheers!

Comment: you need to create the custom layout for the custom notification

Comment: @VishalYadav do you have any example code for that somewhere like Github. actually I need working example to understand.